# UICollectionView inside UITableviewCell after moving the indexpath

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

After following a guide on how to add collectionViews inside a tableViewCell [(here)](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) and then I tried to see if I can switch these two cells.
However, when I try to scroll down the collectionview(horizontally) I get an error that the collectionview index goes out of bounds. I tried to see if adding a reload data for each collection view would help with that issue, but it doesn't... Code below:

```
class BuildTravelPackage: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var optionsTableView: UITableView!

var items = [[PackageOption]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer:)))
    self.optionsTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

    //load data into cells



}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { 
        cell.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 175
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[sourceIndexPath.row]
    items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    items.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    optionsTableView.isEditing = !optionsTableView.isEditing

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = optionsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "optionCell", for: indexPath) as! PackageOptionTableViewCell
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Column:",indexPath.row)
    print("Row:",collectionView.tag)
    //highlght selected cell and load a new cell with infomation? Or load a uiview with date selection
}

func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        if let indexPath = optionsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            optionsTableView.isEditing = !optionsTableView.isEditing

        }
    }
}
}


extension BuildTravelPackage:UICollectionViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[collectionView.tag].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "singleOptionCell", for: indexPath) as! OptionCollectionViewCell
    cell.image.image = items[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row].imageFile
    cell.label.text = items[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is here when you are replacing objects

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
let item = items[sourceIndexPath.row]
items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
items.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
optionsTableView.isEditing = !optionsTableView.isEditing
}
```

try replacing code by

```
 swap(& items[sourceIndexPath.row], & items[destinationIndexPath.row])
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'm going to give this a shot, when I get access to my computer next week, I'll keep you posted on what happens.

Comment: Issue still seems to persist. not sure why.

Comment: Try reloading tableview after moving items i.e inside   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {}